# Need to pre-import module to avoid error

Tags: python, django, python-ldap

I use `python-ldap` inside my `Django` application and that have always worked fine. I am currently in the process of upgrading a lot of deps in my project moving things around wanting to end up with the latest django on alpine and docker.

Trying to execute `./manage shell` (or any other manage commands) suddenly started to give me this error;

```
...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import _ldap
ImportError: Error relocating /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_ldap.so: ber_free: symbol not found
```

`python -c 'import _ldap'` works fine, `./manage.py shell -c 'import _ldap'` barfs with the error above.

Fiddling around, I noticed that if I `import ldap` very early, the error went away.

After a long journey of editing and debugging, I have found that if I add `if entry == 'django.contrib.postgres': import ldap` before https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/apps/config.py#L107, django would be able to `import ldap`.
`module.default_app_config` on L107 is `django.contrib.postgres.apps.PostgresConfig` (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/contrib/postgres/apps.py#L10).

So obviously, postgres import is doing something. But what is it doing with ldap? Is there a name collision somewhere? How can I debug further?

I don't want the solution of "just import ldap on top of your `settings.py`". This is a bug and should be fixed.

- Django: 1.10
- Alpine: 3.4
- Python: 2.7.12
- psycopg2: 2.6.2
- libpq: 9.5.3-r1

Comment: Any update on this?!

Comment: No.. I still got an `import ldap` on top of my settings file. Do you have any more debug-info to add?

Comment: Not really, i took what you gave me and did this: https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/f32818da543bc2586d52ec52de8fa394 other than that no :/ PS, thanks for the snippet :P

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Alpine:3.4 Docker image.

You need to install `python-ldap` from tarball.

```
$ wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/8b/f3/8122b9d8999a67293a5a236f4b9eda009dce76835bb854fb848b1133dbe0/python-ldap-2.4.39.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf python-ldap-2.4.39.tag.gz
$ cd python-ldap-2.4.39
```

Apply this patch on `setup.cfg`:

```
--- setup.cfg
+++ setup.cfg.patch
@@ -2,9 +2,9 @@
 library_dirs = /usr/lib /usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib64
 include_dirs = /usr/include /usr/include/sasl /usr/local/include /usr/local/include/sasl
 defines = HAVE_SASL HAVE_TLS HAVE_LIBLDAP_R
-extra_compile_args =
+extra_compile_args = -g
 extra_objects =
-libs = ldap_r
+libs = ldap_r lber sasl2 ssl crypto

 [install]
 compile = 1
```

As you can see, we just add `lber`, `sasl2`, `ssl` and `crypto` to `libs`.

Then, install `python-ldap`:

```
# python setup.py build
# python setup.py install
```

Source:

- python-ldap [FAQ](https://www.python-ldap.org/faq.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this and upgrading python-ldap to the latest version (3.0.0) solved the issue, as it [includes](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap/pull/173/files) the fix described in the other answer.